# React Native current.contains is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native and I'm trying to detect if the target is a descendant of a specific View Ref.

I'm getting an error: **ref1.current.contains is not a function**

Any help would be appreciated.

```
const ref1 = useRef();

<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  onPress={e => {
    if (ref1.current && !ref1.current.contains(e.target)) {
      alert('You clicked outside of me!');
    }
  }}>
```

... rest of code

```
 <View ref={ref1} style={{backgroundColor: 'green', padding: 20}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine, but how are you assigning the ref1? Make sure there are no typos in your code, and that you are assigning the ref correctly.

e.g.:

```
<View ref={ref1}>{...view code}</View>
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the ref assignment.